# Stubbing requests in controller tests in upgraded rails 5 application

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Before upgrading to rails 5, our app sucessfully stubbed the request.user_agent in controller tests using

```
allow(request).to receive(:user_agent).and_return 'Special Agent'
```

I note that  [stubbing now uses](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html) `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` so 
 I tried using the `#capybara-user_agent` gem with

```
set_custom_user_agent('Special Agent')
```

in my controller tests, but this does not work either.  However, `set_custom_user_agent` does work in the feature specs in rails 4 and rails 5. How do I stub the user agent in controller specs in rails 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to call `request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'agent'` in `before` block? I'm sure you can just modify Rack environment when stubbing does not work